# Infinite Union of non-regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Is infinite union of non-regular languages $L_i$ that form a chain such that $L_i\subseteq L_{i+1}$  always non-regular?

Or is there a possibility that it be ever regular?

Is there an easy way to see this?

Comment: Consider $L_i=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*\ |\ |w|_a-|w|_b\le i\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a non-regular language over $\Sigma$, and let $w_1,w_2,\ldots$ be an enumeration of $\Sigma^*\setminus L$. Define $L_i = L \cup \{ w_j : j \geq i \}$. Each $L_i$ is non-regular (why?), $L_i \subset L_{i+1}$, and $\bigcup_i L_i = \Sigma^*$.

Comment: So in general kleene star of a non-regular language is regular?

Comment: No, for example $\{0^n1^n:n\geq0\}^*$ is not regular (why?).

Comment: Since it contains $0^n1^n0^m1^m$

Comment: Since it contains $\mathsf{only}$ strings of form $0^n1^n0^m1^m\dots$?

Comment: Pumping lemma? Take $xyz = 0^n1^n$ with $y=0$ and pump $y$?